# How to have a reference to a trait and still use original struct?

Tags: rust

My goal is to have a reference counted struct which is referred as a trait in one context and by its concrete type in another. Best explained in code:

```
#![feature(box_syntax)]

use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

trait Employee {
    fn be_managed(&mut self);
}

struct Human;

impl Human {
    fn be_human(&mut self) {
        println!("I'm just a human who needs a mutable self sometimes");
    }
}

impl Employee for Human {
    fn be_managed(&mut self) {
        println!("Off to the salt mines");
    }
}

struct Manager {
    my_employee: Rc<RefCell<Box<Employee + 'static>>>, //'
}

fn main() {
    let mut human1 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(box Human as Box<Employee>));

    let manager1 = Manager {
        my_employee: human1.clone(), // This works due to cast above
    };

    manager1.my_employee.borrow_mut().be_managed();

    human1.borrow_mut().be_human(); // But we can't be human anymore



    let mut human2 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(box Human));

    let manager2 = Manager {
        my_employee: human2.clone(), // This doesn't work
    };

    manager2.my_employee.borrow_mut().be_managed();

    human2.borrow_mut().be_human();
}
```

I want the `Manager` to be able to have any struct implementing the `Employee` trait as `my_employee`, but other references should still be able to call other methods on the original object, ie `be_human`.

Right now I'm getting the following errors from the above code:

```
src/main.rs:37:25: 37:35 error: type `core::cell::RefMut<'_, Box<Employee>>` does not implement any method in scope named `be_human`
src/main.rs:37     human1.borrow_mut().be_human(); // But we can't be human anymore
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:44:22: 44:36 error: mismatched types:
 expected `alloc::rc::Rc<core::cell::RefCell<Box<Employee + 'static>>>`,
    found `alloc::rc::Rc<core::cell::RefCell<Box<Human>>>`
(expected trait Employee,
    found struct `Human`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:44         my_employee: human2.clone(), // This doesn't work
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What's the right approach in this situation?

Comment: Couldn't you implement Employee for RefCell<Box<Human>> and then use an Rc<Employee>? I'm sure something along those lines might end up allowing what you wanted.

Comment: @ker I'm not sure - that's why I'm asking :) Would you mind writing up how that could work as an answer?

Comment: oh sorry, i just noticed this is blocked by https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18248

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: in this answer I will assume that you are willingly NOT using an `enum` because you want `Employee` to be open.*

This issue comes up in about every single language that uses dynamic polymorphism, and the traditional answer is the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

It is not exactly ideal, though, because of the dependencies it introduces, so if necessary you can use the [Acyclic Visitor Pattern](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/acv.pdf); however I advise that you start with a bare bone visitor before delving further.

```
trait EmployeeVisitor {
    fn visit_employee(&self, e: &Employee);
    fn visit_human(&self, h: &Human);
}

trait Employee {
    fn accept(&self, v: &EmployeeVisitor) {
        v.visit_employee(self);
    }
}

impl Employee for Human {
    fn accept(&self, v: &EmployeeVisitor) {
        v.visit_human(self);
    }
 }
```

This is the traditional "every problem can be solved with a layer of indirection", and it incurs the traditional issue of bringing another layer of indirection.